# Identifying numeric and array types in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Is there an existing function in numpy that will tell me if a value is either a numeric type or a numpy array? I'm writing some data-processing code which needs to handle numbers in several different representations (by "number" I mean any representation of a numeric quantity which can be manipulated using the standard arithmetic operators, +, -, *, /, **).

Some examples of the behavior I'm looking for

```
>>> is_numeric(5)
True
>>> is_numeric(123.345)
True
>>> is_numeric('123.345')
False
>>> is_numeric(decimal.Decimal('123.345'))
True
>>> is_numeric(True)
False
>>> is_numeric([1, 2, 3])
False
>>> is_numeric([1, '2', 3])
False
>>> a = numpy.array([1, 2.3, 4.5, 6.7, 8.9])
>>> is_numeric(a)
True
>>> is_numeric(a[0])
True
>>> is_numeric(a[1])
True
>>> is_numeric(numpy.array([numpy.array([1]), numpy.array([2])])
True
>>> is_numeric(numpy.array(['1'])
False
```

If no such function exists, I know it shouldn't be hard to write one, something like

```
isinstance(n, (int, float, decimal.Decimal, numpy.number, numpy.ndarray))
```

but are there other numeric types I should include in the list?

Comment: What should return `is_numeric([1,2,3])` and `is_numeric([1, '2', 3])`?

Comment: False in both cases. I'll edit that into the question.

Comment: What about `numpy.array([numpy.array([1]), numpy.array([2])])`?

Comment: "Testing by trying to do math" will not catch `bool` values, or numpy arrays of them.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As others have answered, there could be other numeric types besides the ones you mention.
One approach would be to check explicitly for the capabilities you want, with something like

```
# Python 2
def is_numeric(obj):
    attrs = ['__add__', '__sub__', '__mul__', '__div__', '__pow__']
    return all(hasattr(obj, attr) for attr in attrs)

# Python 3
def is_numeric(obj):
    attrs = ['__add__', '__sub__', '__mul__', '__truediv__', '__pow__']
    return all(hasattr(obj, attr) for attr in attrs)
```

This works for all your examples except the last one, `numpy.array(['1'])`. That's because `numpy.ndarray` has the special methods for numeric operations but raises TypeError if you try to use them inappropriately with string or object arrays. You could add an explicit check for this like

```
 ... and not (isinstance(obj, ndarray) and obj.dtype.kind in 'OSU')
```

This may be good enough.

But... you can never be *100%* sure that somebody won't define another type with the same behavior, so a more foolproof way is to actually try to do a calculation and catch the exception, something like

```
def is_numeric_paranoid(obj):
    try:
        obj+obj, obj-obj, obj*obj, obj**obj, obj/obj
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

but depending on how often you plan to call use it and with what arguments, this may not be practical (it can be potentially slow, e.g. with large arrays).

Comment: `True,False` and numpy arrays of them look like numbers by these tests, so they'd need to be included in the `and not` clause; assuming that you don't want to do math on them.

Answer (score 7):

Also, numpy has `numpy.isreal` and other similar functions (`numpy.is` + Tab should list them).

They all have their fun corner cases but one of those could be useful.

Comment: `np.isreal(np.array(['bar', 'baz'], dtype='O'))` returns `array([ True,  True], dtype=bool)`. Those dtype='O's are common from pandas text columns, for isntance..

Comment: Also, `np.isreal(np.nan)` returns true. Should probably be renamed `isnoncomplex`...

Answer (score 6):

In general, the flexible, fast, and pythonic way to handle unknown types is to just perform some operation on them and catch an exception on invalid types.

```
try:
    a = 5+'5'
except TypeError:
    print "Oops"
```

Seems to me that this approach is easier than special-casing out some function to determine absolute type certainty.

Comment: It is not an answer to the question but I agree completely.

Comment: @JF, that's true, but I still like this answer to this question.  I think the str*int bug will be easier to catch than the is_numeric function will be to write.  Also, consider that, IIRC, no other mathematical operation is defined where the two operands are str and int.

Comment: `True,False` (and numpy arrays of them) "look like numbers" by this test.

Answer (score 2):

Your `is_numeric` is ill-defined. See my comments to your question.

Other numerical types could be: `long`, `complex`, `fractions.Fraction`, `numpy.bool_`, `numpy.ubyte`, ...

`operator.isNumberType()` returns `True` for Python numbers and `numpy.array`.

Since Python 2.6 you can use `isinstance(d, numbers.Number)` instead of deprecated `operator.isNumberType()`.

Generally it is better to check the capabilities of the object (e.g., whether you can add an integer to it) and not its type.

Comment: Yeah, but if I had an exact definition in mind I could have written the function ;-) I edited in some more information.

Answer (score 1):

`isinstance(numpy.int32(4), numbers.Number)` returns `False`, so that doesn't quite work. `operator.isNumberType()` does work on all the variants of numpy numbers, however, including `numpy.array([1])`.

Comment: This might have used to be the case, but now `isinstance(numpy.int32(4), numbers.Number)` returns `True`.